# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments Exception while invoking constructor

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, reflection

This is the code I'm working on which instantiates and creates object at run time with provided arguments for the constructor.

```
private static void createInstancesFromSpecfication() {
    String[] specifierFileNames = resourceMap.get("instances");
    if (null == specifierFileNames)
        return;
    List<SpecifierObjects> instances = new ArrayList<SpecifierObjects>();
    for (int i = 0; i < specifierFileNames.length; i++) {
        try {
            instances.addAll(XMLFileUtility.readXML(specifierFileNames[i],
                    new ClassInstantiationHandler()));
        } catch (ResourceNotAvailableException | DocumentException
                | ResourceDataFailureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for (Iterator<SpecifierObjects> iterator = instances.iterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        InstanceSpecifierObject instanceSpecifierObject = (InstanceSpecifierObject) iterator
                .next();
        try {
            Class<?> cast = Class.forName(instanceSpecifierObject
                    .getInterfaceName());
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(instanceSpecifierObject
                    .getClassName());
            Constructor<?> constructor = clazz
                    .getConstructor(String[].class);
            Object obj = constructor.newInstance(instanceSpecifierObject
                    .getFilesName());
            objects.put(instanceSpecifierObject.getObjectName(),
                    cast.cast(obj));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception log is :

```
instances=/home/user/workspace/CoreLibs/src/instanceSpecification.xml
/home/user/workspace/CoreLibs/src/instanceSpecification.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.framew.confinit.ApplicationResource.createInstancesFromSpecfication(ApplicationResource.java:87)
at com.framew.confinit.ApplicationResource.importResource(ApplicationResource.java:58)
at com.framew.confinit.ApplicationResource.main(ApplicationResource.java:40)
```

I'm getting the exception in this statement:

```
Object obj = constructor.newInstance(instanceSpecifierObject.getFilesName());
```

instanceSpecifierObject.getFilesNames() retruns an array of filenames as String objects (like String[]). I also tried passing them as Object[], but got the same exception.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The newInstance() method of Class class can invoke zero-argument constructor whereas newInstance() method of Constructor class can invoke any number of arguments. So Constructor class is preferred over Class class.

Comment: try to used the constructor class. If it does not work try to print instanceSpecifierObject.getFilesName(), and make sure it really return a Array. I don't see why it wouldn't work.